# Radius and Set of Convergence for the following Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to find for the following series the radius of convergence and the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ in which the series converges.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}e^n $$ 
help me.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem}

Comment: what $x$ are you talking about?

Comment: You need to rewrite your problem, since $x$ is not present in your series. I was able to address whether or not the series you gave converges but since you didn't provide a power series I cannot provide a radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
a_n=n^n e^n/n!
$$

$$
|a_{n+1}/a_n|=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}e^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}*\frac{n!}{n^n e^n}
$$

$$
|a_{n+1}/a_n|=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}e^{1}}{(n+1)}*\frac{1}{n^n }
$$

$$
|a_{n+1}/a_n|=e\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n
$$

$$
|a_{n+1}/a_n|=e\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$

are you now able to take the limit of this ratio?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually, I want to know that set of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}x^n$. I know that interval of convergence but set... ㅜ.. Any way, thank you so much.